# Is there a nice way to express the opposite of an "override specifier" in Python?

Tags: python, overriding, decorator, python-decorators

C++11 added the [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), which is a promise that a method overrides a parent class's method.  I would like to express the opposite of this, namely that a method is not implemented by any of the parent classes.  Can I express that without metaclasses, for example with a decorator?

This is what I'm currently doing

```py
class EchoSoma(Soma):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        assert not hasattr(super(), 'inject_basic_evidence')

    def inject_basic_evidence(self, basic_in):
        super().fire(basic_in)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that without a metaclass.

Code executing inside a class block has no knowledge of the superclass(es), and "this class" doesn't exist yet.  You need some pre- or post-processing which can only be provided by a metaclass.  Alternatively, you'd need to pass the superclass(es) to the decorator, which would need to reconstruct the MRO, most likely by building a temporary class and checking its `__mro__` attribute.  This is messier than just writing the metaclass you're trying to avoid.

Checking in the `__init__` is not good enough, because that's only done when you instantiate the class, not when the class is initially created.

The metaclass solution looks something like this:

```
class NoOverrideMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct, no_override=None):
        if no_override is None:
            no_override = []
        cls = super().__new__(name, bases, dct)
        for meth_name in no_override:
            assert not hasattr(super(cls, cls), meth_name)
        return cls

class EchoSoma(Soma, metaclass=NoOverideMeta, no_override=['inject_basic_evidence']):

    def inject_basic_evidence(self, basic_in):
        super().fire(basic_in)
```

This example passes the method names by keyword argument, a new feature in 3.x.  Decorators would be cleaner but a bit more complex; you would iterate over `dct` looking for decorated methods.

Comment: Ah, good points.  How would you do it with a metaclass in Python 3?

Comment: Thanks.  I like avoiding metaclasses until something like this is accepted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/python-ideas/metaclass/python-ideas/kyYFsGudqyY/9aRu47_gSc0J

Comment: The author of that post is rather optimistic.  Metaclasses are not going away any time soon, and [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) does not propose eliminating them.

Comment: I don't want to eliminate them either.  The problem with metaclasses is that when you need two of them, you need to use metaclass inheritance, which is very annoying.  For example, it would be normal to combine your `NoOverrideMeta` with Python's `abc.ABCMeta`.